# Excel DB connection: insert, update & delete?

Tags: database, excel

I used the `DATA`-`From Other Sources`-`From SQL Server` controls to import a database table into my Excel workbook. It looks perfect, and refreshing data works like a charm.

However, whenever I make any changes to the table (editing, inserting or deleting rows), I cannot seem to find a way to push these changes to the database. This makes me wonder whether this is actually possible.

Can anybody tell me how to do this, or confirm that this is not supported?

Comment: This is definitely possible, i have some code that does it.

Comment: @HolmesIV Since OP describes using a linked table created from the Data tab of the Ribbon, and there are no VBA tags on this question, the default answer must be that this is not possible. The way this question is framed the OP is asking if there is a setting that will make the linked table bidirectional. There is no such setting.

Comment: @ExcelHero Like i said in my post, just trying to help. Excel has VBA therefore if you cannot do it in simple excel use VBA to do it. I am not here for reputation i am here to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make a 'live' table in Excel by linking to an external data source like you have described in this question, Excel manages this by using a QueryTable object behind the scenes.

QueryTable objects have the ability to be refreshed on demand, and to refresh on a periodic schedule defined by the user.

QuertyTable objects are NOT bi-directional. They can be used to import data into Excel, but not to write changes back to the data source.

QueryTable objects can be manipulated from VBA.

Custom VBA code can be written to automatically write to a data source any  changes made by a user to a table. But this  absolutely requires writing code... it is not a simple option that you can select from the Excel user interface for your table.

> Can anybody tell me how to do this, or confirm that this is not supported?

**Insert, update, and delete are not supported from the Excel user interface.**

Comment: This answer should not actually be marked down. Even though there has been a post to show a work around to the problem, this answer gives valuable information to the OP, explaining that it is not supported and why.  This answer does even indicate that write backs are possible, but require custom VBA, as per the great code provided by Holmes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't have an exact goal other than ,.. Can you, how to ? let me just dump my code that i KNOW works because i use it all the time. This is part of a custom ribbon that is on 20+ computer so they can update/merge their sales information into out database. This should help you out feel free to ask some questions. Basically how it works is creates SQL command, that creates a temp table then merge/updates against our database

```
  Dim adoCN As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim sSQL, sSQLMerge As String
    Dim Starting As Integer

    ''Find the starting point
    For I = 1 To UBound(data, 2) - 1
        If data(I, 0) <> "" Then
            Starting = I
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    '''This primes the temp table
    '' into #tempTable " & vbCrLf
      If LCase(CStr(data(Starting, 0))) = "null" Then

      Else
        sSQL = "select '" & replace(CStr(data(Starting, 0)), "'", "''") & "' as '" & _
                            replace(CStr(data(0, 0)), "'", "''") & "'"
      End If

      For I = 1 To UBound(data, 2) - 1
            If LCase(replace(CStr(data(Starting, I)), "'", "''")) = "null" Then
                sSQL = sSQL & ", '' as '" & _
                                replace(CStr(data(0, I)), "'", "''") & "'"
            Else
                sSQL = sSQL & ", '" & replace(CStr(data(Starting, I)), "'", "''") & "' as '" & _
                                      replace(CStr(data(0, I)), "'", "''") & "'"
            End If
      Next
          sSQL = sSQL & ", getdate() as 'UpdateDate', suser_sname() as 'UpdatedBy' into #tempTable " & vbCrLf



        ' this adds all the data to the temp table
      For I = Starting + 1 To UBound(data, 1)
            If replace(CStr(data(I, 0)), "'", "''") = "" Then 'Checks to see ifs it has prop id, if not skip

            Else
                If LCase(replace(CStr(data(I, 0)), "'", "''")) = "null" Then 'checks to see if null if so add blank
                    sSQL = sSQL & "union Select ''"
                Else
                    sSQL = sSQL & "union Select '" & replace(CStr(data(I, 0)), "'", "''") & "'" 'if not null add value
                End If
                For II = 1 To UBound(data, 2) - 1
                    If LCase(replace(CStr(data(I, II)), "'", "''")) = "null" Then
                        sSQL = sSQL & ", ''"
                    Else
                        sSQL = sSQL & ", '" & replace(CStr(data(I, II)), "'", "''") & "'"
                    End If
                Next
                sSQL = sSQL & ", getdate(), suser_sname() " & vbCrLf
            End If
      Next

'GuidanceInputForm.SellerConditioning.Text = sSQL
''UserForm1.Label1.Caption = Len(sSQLMerge)
'GuidanceInputForm.Show


      ''Add Merge code
            sSQLMerge = "Merge CommercialSandbox..MasterDataTape as t" & vbCrLf & _
                    " Using #temptable as S on (replace(t.[Property ID], '-','') = replace(s.[Property ID], '-','') and replace(t.[Event ID], '-','') = replace(s.[Event ID], '-','')) " & vbCrLf & _
                    " When NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT([" & data(0, 0) & "]"
            For I = 1 To UBound(data, 2) - 1
                sSQLMerge = sSQLMerge & ", [" & data(0, I) & "]"
            Next
                sSQLMerge = sSQLMerge & ", UpdateDate, UpdatedBy"
                sSQLMerge = sSQLMerge & ") VALUES (s.[" & data(0, 0) & "]"

            For I = 1 To UBound(data, 2) - 1
                sSQLMerge = sSQLMerge & ", s.[" & data(0, I) & "]"
            Next
                sSQLMerge = sSQLMerge & ", s.UpdateDate, s.UpdatedBy"
               sSQLMerge = sSQLMerge & ") " & vbCrLf & _
                    " When MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.[" & data(0, 0) & "] = s.[" & data(0, 0) & "]"

            For I = 1 To UBound(data, 2) - 1
                sSQLMerge = sSQLMerge & ", t.[" & data(0, I) & "] = s.[" & data(0, I) & "]"
            Next
                sSQLMerge = sSQLMerge & ", t.UpdateDate = s.UpdateDate, t.UpdatedBy = s.UpdatedBy"
                sSQLMerge = sSQLMerge & ";"

'GuidanceInputForm.SellerConditioning.Text = sSQLMerge
''UserForm1.Label1.Caption = Len(sSQLMerge)
'GuidanceInputForm.Show


      sConnString = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=ERPT01LAX01US.prod.auction.local\EDWALT;Database=Commercialsandbox;Integrated Security = SSPI"

      Set adoCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
      adoCN.CommandTimeout = 0

      adoCN.Open sConnString
      adoCN.Execute sSQL
      adoCN.Execute sSQLMerge
      adoCN.Close
```

Comment: Neat solution to create functionality that is not available by default.  The OP also mentioned a DELETE option.  Since you have the data-set in a temp table, it will be possible to join the temp table to the original table, and then delete the records that are un-match from the temp table. Very neat!  ... but also perhaps a bit dangerous.

Comment: @RichardVivian yeah, well if you look through all this is really doing is creating a sql command that will do what you want it to do. So delete would be just as easy, just need to devise a way to get your where clause.

Comment: I am thinking you can do something like this.  DELETE from OriginalTable LEFT JOIN #TempTable ON OriginalTable.Key = #TempTable.Key WHERE #TempTable.Key IS NULL.  That will delete any record not in the temp table. (I.e deleted in Excel).  It will also delete any new record created since the last refresh in Excel, so perhaps some DateTImeStamp filter also needed to prevent that.